# Configuring django-celery-email with django-anymail

Tags: django, email, sendgrid, django-celery, django-anymail

I am using django-anymail(sendgrid) to send emails in my web app. I would like to let the emails send in asynchronous manner without letting the users wait for some time.So, how can I configure django-celery-email with django-anymail.

Now, my email config. is:

```
ANYMAIL = {
"SENDGRID_API_KEY": os.environ.get('SENDGRID_API_KEY')
}
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.sendgrid.EmailBackend"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the django-celery-email [readme](https://github.com/pmclanahan/django-celery-email#using-django-celery-email):

> By default django-celery-email will use Django's builtin SMTP email backend… If you'd like to use another backend, you may set it in `CELERY_EMAIL_BACKEND` just like you would normally have set `EMAIL_BACKEND` before you were using Celery.

So in your settings.py:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend"
CELERY_EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.sendgrid.EmailBackend"  # your setting from before
```

Also, note that django-celery-email doesn't know about Anymail's [extra sending options](https://anymail.readthedocs.io/en/stable/sending/anymail_additions/#esp-send-options-anymailmessage), like `metadata`, `tags`, `template_id`, `envelope_sender`, etc. If you use any of those, you'll need to let django-celery-email know about them in your settings:

```
CELERY_EMAIL_MESSAGE_EXTRA_ATTRIBUTES = ['metadata', 'tags']  # or whatever you use
```

(More info in [this issue](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail/issues/79#issuecomment-345814865).)